# How to normalize a JSON file into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file named stocks.json that looks as follows (note the **lack of square brackets** in the source file):

```
{"MSFT": {"exchange": "Nasdaq", "price": 275.79}, "FB": {"exchange": "Nasdaq", "price": 320.22}, "TSLA": {"exchange": "Nasdaq", "price": 990.83}, "GE": {"exchange": "Nasdaq", "price": 83.20}}
```

I would like to transform this data into a Pandas dataframe that looks as follows:

```
symbol     exchange     price
MSFT       Nasdaq       275.79
FB         Nasdaq       320.22
TSLA       Nasdaq       990.83
GE         NYSE          83.20
```

My attempt is:

```
import pandas as pd

stock_data = pd.read_json('stocks.json', lines=True)
stock_data_normalized = pd.json_normalize(stock_data)
```

Unfortunately, I get the following when calling `stock_data_normalized`:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Any assistance would be most appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just using the `pd.DataFrame()` constructor, and then transpose and reset the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index().rename({'index': 'symbol'}, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  symbol exchange   price
0   MSFT   Nasdaq  275.79
1     FB   Nasdaq  320.22
2   TSLA   Nasdaq  990.83
3     GE   Nasdaq    83.2
```

Comment: This solution results in a column named "0" with elements that look like:  `{"exchange": "Nasdaq", "price": 275.79}`.  How would I "unpack" that dictionary into separate columns?

Comment: Really? What data are you exactly using? It must be different from what you're showing. Also, what's your pandas version?

Comment: Yes, the structure of the data in the source file is EXACTLY the same as what I provided.  The Pandas version is 1.3.4.  Did you apply your solution on the structure of the data I provided?

Comment: Yes, I copied all your json, put `d = ` before it, and ran it, like this: `d = {"MSFT": {"exchange": "Nasdaq", "price": ...`

Comment: Maybe your data is nested in another object or array or something?

Comment: Maybe the difference is that I read the file in using `stocks = pd.read_json('stocks.json', lines=True)`, then applied your solution as df = `pd.DataFrame(stocks).T.reset_index().rename({'index': 'symbol'}, axis=1)` ?

Comment: Oh, probably when `lines=True`, `read_json` returns a list of JSON objects, right?

Comment: Yes!  I needed to remove `lines=True`.  Your solution works perfectly for me.  Thank you!